# Error when installing Xubuntu: 'grub-efi-amd64-signed'package failed to install into /target/

Tags: grub2, system-installation, xubuntu

I'm trying to install Xubuntu on a computer with windows7. I downloaded Xubuntu and made a bootable USB key with success. During installation process I got a message like this and then it stopped

> The 'grub-efi-amd64-signed' package failed to install into /target/. Without the GRUB boot loader, the install system will not boot.

What am I supposed to do here?

Comment: You said installation was successful, then said it was running...!  please be clear. Were you trying to install it on USB?

Comment: Actually I used the wrong words. I could download xubuntu on a USB key, with success. Then I tries to install it on my computer wich has windows seven, and this message about the grub appeared

Answer (score 1):

Did you try following this guide [UEFI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Creating_an_UEFI_partition)? It really helped me out. Seems to me that you need to go into Boot Menu in you BIOS and select the UEFI: USB Hard Drive.